# How to Display List

Tags: c#, list, listview, asp.net-mvc-5, ienumerable

** Help Please**
I want to display the service list from the database here inserted data multiple table when I will try to display see the Error Details :

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ICBCRM.WEB.tbl_Service]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ICBCRM.WEB.tbl_User'.**

**View Model**

```
@model IEnumerable<ICBCRM.WEB.tbl_Service>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServiceDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServiceDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServiceDuration)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tbl_ServiceName.ServiceName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tbl_User.UserName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ServiceList()
{
  var list = db.tbl_Service.ToList();
  return View(list);
}
```

**Model Class**

```
    public partial class tbl_Service
{
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public string ServiceDescription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ServiceDate { get; set; }
    public string ServiceDuration { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserServiceId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ServiceNameId { get; set; }

    public virtual tbl_ServiceName tbl_ServiceName { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_User tbl_User { get; set; }
}
```

[Please See The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muvcN.png)

[This is My Database Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvxUX.png)

Comment: What's the name of your view? Is it ServiceList?  I suspect the controller isn't loading the view you are showing here, but another where the Model is of type ICBCRM.WEB.tbl_User

Comment: Do you have model in your layout? if yes delete it

Comment: @Jon Roberts   - Yes ServiceList is my Model Class

Comment: I am using the Relational Database, 1. tbl_User    2. tbl_Service   User submit data and store it service list, Now I want to display Service list . But here found some errors.

Comment: I didn't mean the name of your model class, what's the name of the layout you are trying to open when you "return View(list);" in your controller. I suspect it's not the one you think it is.

Comment: @Jon Roberts
View Name is ServiceList and Layout Name is _Layout